# MVC3 app doesn't work on IIS7.5 in virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

My MVC3 app shows "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" exception when I've deployed it to IIS7.5 to virtual directory, but if I deploy it to not to the virtual directory it works ok.
AppPool is the same for 2 cases with virtual directory and w/o it, my virtual directory is not converted to an Application.

What should I do to make my app run on a virtual directory?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try making it an application rather than a virtual directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely need to have your MVC application running as an Application, it doesn't work like web pages

Comment: when I converted to application all my css styles gone. What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: is access to any page of your app locked off unless you're logged into it?

Comment: I don't have any authentication on my site.

Comment: want to add, style is present, but images are disappeared. I added them in my css file like this "url(/Content/images/img01.jpg)".

Comment: I fixed my problem by changing images url to this "url(images/img01.jpg)".